# Translate joomla K2 template sentence

Tags: joomla, translation, joomla3.0, multilingual, k2

I have a joomla website with 5 subtemplate K2.
The website is multilingual and I want to translate some sentences in subtemplate.

Where I can put this translation ? 
I think it's in **de-DE.com_k2.ini** but in the next K2's update, sentence will be erase ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either edit the appropriate files in

```
/language/overrides
```

or use the **Language override** feature in your administrator backend (Administrator-Extensions-Language management-Overrides). There you can search for text, find the language constants, and provide your custom localisations, which will persist across components' and Joomla! updates.